# Bootstrap 3 Responsive Menu - Navbar spacing issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having the following problem:

The `Bootstrap 3` navbar according to the documentation has three different dividers as defined here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default

- **nav navbar-nav**
- **navbar-form navbar-left**
- **nav navbar-nav navbar-right**

However, I don't have any navigation links to input in the `nav navbar-nav` section next to brand; I only make use of `navbar-form navbar-left` and `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` so I decided to remove `nav navbar-nav` entirely.

The issue that gives me is that when the menu collapses there is a weird spacing between the `navbar` and the `form`. What is the proper way  to implement what i'm trying to do and / or avoid this issue?

**Update** If I drop `nav navbar-nav navbar-right` I get the same spacing issue except for the bottom for the bottom of the collapsed menu. It seems that `Bootstrap` expects  *something* to be there; is there a way around this?

**Update2** Default Bootstrap 3 Navbar http://jsfiddle.net/wmkp595e/

- Spacing issue between the `search form` and `navbar` http://jsfiddle.net/wmkp595e/1/

Comment: You're talking about the double lines after the header and before the form. Apparently this is the way it is, since it's always been there if you put the form right after the header. http://jsfiddle.net/wmkp595e/2/ -- I just remove the border on the form

Comment: Here's another version: http://jsfiddle.net/wmkp595e/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the Bootstrap 3 css (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) of the navbar before the media queries -- which is the one used by the small viewport menu, you'll see that the borders are there no matter where you put your form, so if it's right after the `.navbar-header` you will have double rules and a padding on the top that you may or may not want to remove.

```
.navbar-form {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}
```

If you put your form right after it, write some css to address this, since your css will come after the Bootstrap CSS, you will need a max width or yours will screw up the padding:

```
@media (max-width:767px) {
   .navbar-form {
      border-top:0px;
      padding-top:0;
   }
}
```

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wmkp595e/3**

Comment: So, the padding is added by both `navbar-form` and `nav navbar-nav`?

Comment: There's padding on the navbar-brand, navbar-form, and navbar-nav

Comment: All heights in the navbar are (whether small or large) due to the content and the top and bottom padding.

Comment: Ah, I see. The other one was margin that is why I didn't understand. `.nav,.navbar-nav {margin:0px;}` Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
nav navbar-nav navbar-form navbar-left navbar-right
```

are utility classes that sets positioning of the element,

can you make a fiddle or show the site?

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior with Bootstrap. If there is too much content in the top navigation then when the browser window size is smaller it will cause the elements in the header to wrap. There are a couple of ways to deal with it:

- You can reduce the amount of space that is being used in the navigation by either reducing padding or making your navigation links use less text or sizing down your input elements. This is probably the simplest option.
- Alternatively you can edit the `@media` CSS in bootstrap to allow the `navbar-toggle` button to activate sooner.